# How can I reach local file instead of controller url having app deployed on Apache2?

Tags: apache2, deployment, ubuntu-18.04

My web app is running after being deployed on Apache2 (local OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). There is a plethora of controller-related urls like `localhost://get_id/<id>` or `localhost://delete/<id>`. Whenever I enter them into search mask, page of my we site appears here, well. What brings me into misunderstanding is a problem of opening any local file inside Apache root directory (`/var/www/html`) instead of getting content by urls. To be more specific: I have file `sample.txt` within directory `/var/www/html/samples`. Now I need to display what this file contains but after typing `localhost/samples/sample.txt` (suggesting that `localhost` file source is just  `/var/www/html`) it fails to show anything like `sample.txt` though `Not found`.
 Virtual host configurations are defined as below:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-access.log combined

        <Location />
                ProxyPass unix:/var/www/html/site/site.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
                ProxyPassReverse unix:/var/www/html/site/site.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I see clear it's a case of missing configuration for a virtual host - which exactly? I was looking for any earlier posts, questions and answers (that's  pretty simple issue, so it was responded in the past, I'm sure), but without success. Let me note I'm a newbie to server technologies like Apache, my experience doesn't enable me to solve that matter myself so far. So, how do I want to implement file paths instead of web site url, essentially? Any pointer will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you type "localhost://samples/sample.txt" ?   If this would be into the address bar of a browser, then you need to study how an URL is constructed.   Would you mean "http : //localhost/samples/sample.txt"  (without the spaces) ?

Comment: I put `localhost/samples/sample.txt` into browser address bar before getting `Not found` response

Comment: Just updated, there was a mistake in my original sample of address bar input

Comment: At first sight your VirtualHost seems to be missing a "root /var/www/html".